# Logo design: which file format

Tags: logo, file-format

I had someone design a logo for me and I told him it needed to be in a format that I can resize without losing quality and transparent.

He sent me a transparent `PNG` file.

1. If I use a site like pixlr or canva to resize it then I lose the transparency.
2. If I use the file he sent me then the transparency works but the size is wrong.

How do I use the file he sent me and be able to resize it without losing transparency so I can use it on my website? Thank you for your help.

Comment: The duplicate is from the perspective of a designer not a client, but that should answer your question; in short you should have a lot more than a single PNG and *at least* a vector format.

Answer (score 3):

To be 100% covered for all current and future situations you should ask for a **vector version**, which `PNG` is not. Specifically you need to request an AI (ideally) or EPS or PDF or SVG format.

With a **vector version** you can then generate in either Photoshop or Illustrator, or have others generate for you, any kind of artwork in any size for either print or web, in any format or resolution. True professionals know these things and will never deliver a logo in `PNG` only.

The `PNG` you have received has some limitations already for web usage, and definitely not suited for print work.

You could also ask for a few *useful* non-vector versions (`PNG`, `JPG`, etc) for your immediate needs and make sure these are saved exactly as you need them, assuming you can't use Photoshop or Illustrator yourself to process vector formats.

Comment: For regular re-use, I think your "ideally AI" is slightly overkill, as it requires Adobe Illustrator (and not a too old or too new version as well). But, lacking a proper description of how the logo would be  re-used by the OP, I cannot think of a reasoanble alternative vector format either. Add SVG perhaps?

Comment: Added SVG and updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can request Ai or EPS file format to resize the logo with transparency without losing image quality.